# Impact of Data Distribution on Loss Functions' Suitability

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, deep-learning, loss-functions

I read at a place that mean squared loss doesn't work well with multi-modal data.

I had heard that it is also not robust to outliers and Mean absolute error is more robust.

1. How do I choose a loss function? How can I systematically think about choosing my loss function for a regression or classification task.
2. Could you explain what differences are there in the behavior of famous loss functions in regression and classification?
3. What is the impact of multi-modality on the effectiveness of loss functions towards guiding the learning in Machine learning? If data is bimodal, I should not use mean squared loss? What are the tests to derive these kind of conclusions about a particular loss function.

Comment: Regarding point (1), consider that for "sum of squared absolute error" a single data point with a large error can dominate the regression, as that large error is *squared* - giving sensitivity to outliers. For mean absolute error this is not the case, so sensitivity to outliers is reduced. If you want the maximum error to be as small as possible, fit to the lowest maximum absolute error. If you have a very wide dynamic range, consider fitting using the relative error rather than absolute error, such that a 5% error on the low end fits as well as a 5% error on the high end. All have use cases.